# Recover remix deleted contract and BNB

Tags: remix

I deployed.. added funds... nothing happened. I went to another tab in chrome then came back and noticed metamask was disconnected. I reconnected deployed the same contract left it overnight but nothing. I deleted the contract which i have just realised i may now not get back the .4 bnb i deposited into that contract. I deployed again but did not fund as i though i already funded but still nothing. I think my chrome ad blocker may have something to do with this. How can i get back my .4bnb and my deleted contract?

Answer (score 0):

Most contracts currently receiving BNB cannot do anything with them, as the BNB received cannot be withdrawn. In order for us to understand whether it is possible to recover or not I need to see your contract and the hash of your transaction.

Please provide the hash involved, please.

---

**Edit: my answer on 02/16/2021:**

Thanks for providing more information and the hash.

I analyzed your TXID and also found the other transaction of the other 0.2 BNB:
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x66b3a3846f1e4824b32c55c7c959002af18b2ef37da308af9ef2b4c95b310cc1

You would have used flash loan contracts on mainnet, but unfortunately the contracts are from scammers. The money that goes into these contracts is diverted to another address: https://bscscan.com/address/0x896a04da39500882652c0de2cab8d806338505e1

The scammer who owned the above external address stole 4.1 BNB from victims.

The part of the code that diverts your money is statements that an alleged route address is on the IFPS or that a library is on the IFPS. Went in there and never comes back.

**My advice:**
Always be very careful with codes that appear on the internet, especially when they are not from reliable sources and make promises of big gains.

There are many scammers promising big gains with flash loan trades using dangerous contracts, but they are nothing but scammers.

First review all the code to see if there is something about embezzlement, then try to implement and study it on test net or talk to an expert when real funds are involved.